# understanding auto reference counting

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

The way I understand auto reference counting is this:

If an object is going to be consumed by various classes, it should be type "strong" so that it stays around while others might be doing stuff with it.

If an object is simply an internal structure for a class, it can be type "weak", because it will go away once the current class implementation is done dealing with it.

Is there more to it than this?

Here is an example of what I imagine:

```
#import "World.h"
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *barArray;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *bazString;
@end

@implementation Foo
-(void)sendTheArrayIntoTheWorld {
    self.barArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"lonely item"];
    [World takeTheArray:self.barArray]; // array is strong so it can exist indefinitely
}

-(void)useThatString {
    self.bazString = "weak old string"; // string is weak because it should be discarded when it's no longer needed here...
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly how ARC works. It boils down to this:

- Strong references are the only ones that keep objects alive
- An object needs at least one `strong` reference to remain alive
- Weak references do not keep objects alive- if there are 100 weak references to an object but no strong references, then the object will be released
- Assigning a value to a `weak` property without referencing it elsewhere will result in its immediate deallocation, as with your `bazString`. If you try accessing that string after you assign it a value (unless it is being owned by another object, like an array, which it is not in your case), you'll find that it is `nil`.

This means that weak references should be used for objects that you don't necessarily 'control,' like delegates. If you use a strong reference for a delegate and the delegate has a strong reference on you, then neither object will ever be deallocated. This is called a retain cycle.

**If you need an object to stay alive until you are done with it, use `strong`. Otherwise, use `weak`.**

You can read much more about the intricacies and features of ARC [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: and when you do "@property (readonly)", that is not changing the reference count at all, correct?

Comment: Correct. You'll notice that `readonly` can be used for objects and primitives alike- it has not effect on the property's retain count, only whether or not it can be changed by another object.

Comment: also--  is this appropriate then?  http://pastie.org/4541177   ...  because the game class is going to instantiate a SpaceShip and, say the ship behaves a certain way based off of what level it's on-- it's going to pass the level to the created space ship...  So in this case, the SpaceShip class should have a weak reference to the level object, because the game class is already holding onto it...  Is that the right way to think about it?

Comment: also when Apple says "weak references are not supported in 10.6 / iOS4", what does that mean?  How can ARC be supported but not weak references?  What happens when properties are declared with weak references on those platforms?

Comment: Yes, that hierarchy will work. "Weak references are not supported..." means that if you are making an app for those platforms, you have to use `unsafe_unretained` instead of `weak`. It is essentially the same except it does NOT nil out an object once its retain count is 0. That is an important distinction. There are other small differences too, which you can read about in the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: ok thanks..  One final question, are there any drawbacks to sticking with manual memory management in an iOS project?  Like, if I choose to not use arc, and do retain, release, autorelease, etc--  Will that come back to bite me later on (iOS6 for example) ?

Comment: Yes and no. Technically all that ARC does is put the proper `retain` `release` `autorelease` calls into your code where necessary, so there is no difference between compiled ARC and non-ARC code. **BUT**, ARC is capable of optimizations and attention to detail that we humans simply cannot attain. I would highly recommend the switch to ARC.